# Prove that $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given $U = \{ (x, y, z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 | x-3y+z = 0 \}$ and $V = \{ (x, y, z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 | x+2z = 0 \}$, prove that $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm new to Linear Algebra so, I'd really love some definitions for where the explanations come from. Thanks!

Comment: To show that a set is a subspace, you can do it by showing that (1) the zero vector is in the set, (2) for any two vectors $x$ and $y$ in the set, $x+y$ is in the set, and (3) for any vector $x$ in the set and any scalar $a$, $ax$ is in the set.

Comment: @twosigma I thought the definition was to show that x-y is in the set

Comment: Oh ok, there are several equivalent definitions. So you can just follow the one given to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in the comments that your definition of subspace is that for all $\mathbf{w}_1, \mathbf{w}_2 \in W$, we have also $\mathbf{w}_1 - \mathbf{w}_2 \in W$. Technically you should also verify that the set is non-empty, but that's not a big deal in this case since $\mathbf{0} = (0,0,0)$ is in each set.

Okay, let's show that $U$ is a subspace. We've already noted that $\mathbf{0}\in U$, so we don't have to worry about that. Let $\mathbf{u} = (x, y, z)$ and $\mathbf{u}' = (x', y', z')$ be arbitrary elements of $U$. Then $\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u'} = (x - x', y - y', z - z')$, so it suffices to show that $(x - x') - 3(y - y') + (z - z') = 0$, because then $\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}' \in U$ by definition of $U$.

Now, it is a simple rearrangement that
$$
(x - x') - 3(y - y') + (z - z') = (x - 3y + z) - (x' - 3y' + z')
$$

But since $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2 \in U$, by definition of U we have $x - 3y + z = x' - 3y' + z' = 0$, which means that the above expression is zero, as required.

The method for $V$ is exactly the same (and actually slightly easier to execute since you only have to deal with two variables), so I'll leave that to you!

By the way, I think the reason for the downvotes is that you haven't shown how you've approached the problem; it's usually considered good practice to say what you've tried, what ideas you've had, what you're struggling with, etc. Just a note for the future :)

Edit: As helpfully pointed out in a comment, I also need to show that $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication! This can be done similarly, for if $\mathbf{w} = (x, y, z) \in W$, then for all $\lambda \in F$ (where $F$ is our field) we have $\lambda \mathbf{w} = (\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z)$, and 
$$
(\lambda x-3\lambda y + \lambda z) = \lambda(x - 3y + z) = \lambda 0 = 0
$$
so $\lambda \mathbf{w} \in W$ by definition of $W$.

Comment: What about showing closure under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Yes good point - have edited. +1

Comment: @Qwertiops Hell, this is the same method I did before seeing your comment so thanks a lot for clarifying everything a bit better for my understanding and confirming my solution.

Comment: @Qwertiops Also, thank you for the note on my downvote. I'll make sure next time I will be clearer. ^^